# Differentiate between class and cast class members in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, casting

I have a generic class which exposes the same object both as the base class type and the child class type as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    var genericTest = new GenericTestClass<ChildClass>(new ChildClass());
    var baseVal = genericTest.Entity.ValBase;
    var castBaseVal = genericTest.EntityCast.ValBase;
    var castBaseChildVal = genericTest.EntityCast.Val;
    //var wontWork = genericTest.Entity.Val; //AS EXPECTED WILL NOT COMPILE
}

public class GenericTestClass<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass Entity {get;}
    public T EntityCast => Entity as T;
    public GenericTestClass(T myClass)
    {
        Entity = myClass;
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public int ValBase => 1;
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public int Val => 2;
}
```

As expected the line `var wontWork = genericTest.Entity.Val` will not compile, and I want to verify this differing behaviour in unit tests.

My question is how best to demonstrate the differing `Entity` and `EntityCast` behaviours so as to confirm casting worked correctly? Obviously they both return `ChildClass` when checking the type, so I cannot use `Assert.IsType<BaseClass>(genericTest.Entity)`.

Thanks

Comment: you would need to manually cast `Entity` to desired type to have access to members. ie `var val = ((ChildClass)genericTest.Entity).Val;`

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want to _test_ that property `Entity` has declared (compile-time) type `BaseClass`, and that `BaseClass` has no property called `Val`? I cannot understand why. `var p = typeof(GenericTestClass<>).GetProperty("Entity")` will give you the property info. You can see its `.PropertyType`. It is equal to `typeof(BaseClass)`. You can see that `typeof(BaseClass).GetProperty("Val")` gives null, there is no `Val` property there. But I do not understand the design of `GenericTestClass<>`.

Comment: I want to test that if this call (`var a = genericTest.EntityCast`) then `a` will be seen by the compiler as type `ChildClass` whereas if this call (`var b = genericTest.Entity`) then `b` will be seen as `BaseClass`

Comment: The reason for this design, is in actual use, the child classes are generated automatically and can have hundreds of fields not in the base class. In my model code, it is sometimes much easier to write the code and use intellisense using `class.Entity` rather than `class.EntityCast`

Comment: On reflection I think you are correct @JeppeStigNielsen. The `Entity` member of `GenericTestClass` is superfluous. If you would like to specify that as a response I will mark it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a comment. It seems more natural to swap the roles of the properties.

```
public class GenericTestClass<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass Entity => EntityCast;
    public T EntityCast { get; }
    public GenericTestClass(T myClass)
    {
        EntityCast = myClass;
    }
}
```

---

If I understand you correctly, this may be what you want:

```
var properyEntity = typeof(GenericTestClass<>).GetProperty("Entity");
Assert.AreEqual(typeof(BaseClass), propertyEntity.PropertyType);
Assert.IsNull(typeof(BaseClass).GetProperty("Val"));
```

You can also use `GenericTestClass<ChildClass>` instead of just `GenericTestClass<>`.

But I am not sure a "test" like this is meaningful.

---

You can also have a method (of questionable value!) like this:

```
static Type GetCompiletimeTypeOf<T>(T dummy) => typeof(T);
```

Then you can do:

```
Assert.AreEqual(GetCompiletimeTypeOf(genericTest.Entity), typeof(BaseClass));
```

with `var genericTest = new GenericTestClass<ChildClass>(new ChildClass());` like in your question.

Comment: Thanks. The GetCompileTypeOf provides the technical answer I was looking for. For anyone else reading this I would add I went with original comment above of @JeppeStigNielsen and decided to refactor. There is no need for non-cast member.